# Change Plank theme back to default

Tags: plank

I have changed my Plank theme using elementary Tweaks, but there doesn't exist the default theme option. My question is, how can I get back to the stock Plank theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. Had to click "revert to default" button.

Answer (score 3):

To facilitate switching in the future you can add a default theme to the list:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/plank/themes
ln -s /usr/share/themes/elementary/plank ~/.local/share/plank/themes/Pantheon
```

After that, the default theme will be named `Pantheon`.